# Filters for solar eclipse and solar feature viewing

Tags: the-sun, telescope, amateur-observing, solar-eclipse

I have

- a [Vixen ED100SF ED](http://www.universetoday.com/19454/the-vixen-ed100sf-refractor-superb-optical-quality/) refracting telescope and
- [10x50 6.5 Bushnell Legend Porro Prism](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/246657-REG/Bushnell_191050_10x50_Legend_Binocular.html) binoculars

and would like to outfit both with filters for solar eclipse viewing. I gather the basic setup simply involves finding an appropriate filter, that fits the equipment, but I'm new to this and the [range of options](http://www.telescope.com/Gift-Center/Sun-Spot/pc/7/483.uts?currentIndex=0&pageSize=22&defaultPageSize=20&mode=viewall&categoryId=7&subCategoryId=483&type=thumbnail2level) is bewildering. Ideally I'd also like something that allows me to see solar features, but I gather that these can be quite expensive.

What are my options (or a good reference on options) for viewing solar eclipses and solar features? Would something like an ["eyepiece" filter](http://www.daystarfilters.com/Quark/CALCIUMQuark.shtml) work on its own for safe viewing, or would my telescope require something different?

Answer (score 3):

You mustn't use an eyepiece filter. It is very very dangerous. In my opinion the best is buying an Astrosolar paper, that isn't expensive and you can see very well an eclipse. If you want to see solar features you must spend more and you need an H-alpha filter, but the view with that is amazing

Answer (score 2):

To prevent eye damage, a filter covering the objective (full aperture, energy rejection, safety film, etc.) is mandatory.
An eyepiece filter also needs an objective filter to protect against overheating.
Sunspots are visible without an expensive narrowband filter.
A filter for the hydrogen-alpha (H$\alpha$) line or the calcium line you linked to
can show more detail within the solar disk or prominences around the edge.
Sky & Telescope has several [articles about observing the Sun](http://www.skyandtelescope.com/observing/celestial-objects-to-watch/sun/).

Comment: So if cover the objective fully with something appropriate (i.e. that would work on its own for safe solar viewing) can I then get an H-alpha eyepiece like the one I linked to in order to see solar detail. Would that combination work like a full-objective H-alpah feature (though presumably much less expensive)?

Comment: I expect so but have not tried it myself. An astronomy club member near you may have some equipment you could try before buying your own.